# Snapping Elements in Layout to Neatlines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, layouts, snapping

I was wondering if there is a way to snap the center of an element to a neatline using ArcGIS 10?

For example I have a neatline running down the center of the map in layout view and I want the center of the title element (text box) to snap onto that neatline. Then I can have the Title and subtitle aligned even though they are different sizes.

GIS for the government entity I worked for last had this function. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to make it work on this place’s GIS.

Comment: You could add a guide at the neatline and snap to that. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_rulers,_guides,_and_grids

Comment: Align centres with right click